# SAP Crystal Reports Viewer does not display in browser

Tags: crystal-reports, report, viewer

I own a ASP.NET web project with framework 4.5. Is installed and implemented an SAP report for VS2012 Crystal Reports Developer.

Making in Local report, it works correctly in browsers (Chrome, Firefox, IE) and the data in the correct exit. Now, at the time of publishing (on another server) the first thing we did was install the same version of SAP, so that there are the necessary libraries etc..

The problem I have is that the block of Report Viewer, I mean, what is the repot container, not shown in the browser, open the window where is this embedded but not shown anything in the Report Viewer, what the report will look even less.

Thinking it might be a data error or something, I tried to change the report and put a blank, where all that is shown is a text, and no connections or anything like that and removing the code that is not needed in the code behind, I just stopped loading the report.

In new local works, but on the web published, the Report Viewer still be

Anybody can help me a bit? I looking for some information about it but what I find in forums related, is that the report is not seen, but nothing of Report Viewer.

Thank you very so much in advance.

PS: I have checked the server log for error to any issue or Asp.Net Crystal Reports and not leave anything.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I have smiler problem and found a solution.

I think there is some problem in finding Resource from default `Resource-Uri` for formatting of crystal report.

For proper formatting
Copy `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\aspnet_client\system_web\4_0_30319\crystalreportviewers13` this folder into your project.

And past these lines into your web.config file

```
<configSections>
<sectionGroup name="businessObjects">
  <sectionGroup name="crystalReports">
    <section name="rptBuildProvider" type="CrystalDecisions.Shared.RptBuildProviderHandler, CrystalDecisions.Shared, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304, Custom=null" />
       <section name="crystalReportViewer" type="System.Configuration.NameValueSectionHandler" />
  </sectionGroup>
</sectionGroup>
  </configSections>
```

```
<businessObjects>
  <crystalReports>
    <rptBuildProvider>
      <add embedRptInResource="true" />
    </rptBuildProvider>
    <crystalReportViewer>
          <add key="ResourceUri" value="/crystalreportviewers13" />
  </crystalReportViewer>
  </crystalReports>
</businessObjects>
```

[Check this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ef56f72b-7ede-47d8-ba9e-9e63b9ac0203/bobj-is-undefined?forum=vscrystalreports)

This will help you.

Answer (score 4):

Solved.... 100 % 'll work. Follow the below two steps:

1.Update Application Folder.

> "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\aspnet_client\system_web\4_0_30319\crystalreportviewers13"
>       into your application root folder asp below snapshot.
>   [image]

2. Update Web.Config file by the following code.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

After copying the folder ***"C:\inetpub\wwwroot\aspnet_client\system_web\4_0_30319\crystalreportviewers13"*** into your application root folder, be sure you copy and paste the give code:

```
<configSections>
<sectionGroup name="businessObjects">
  <sectionGroup name="crystalReports">
    <section name="rptBuildProvider" type="CrystalDecisions.Shared.RptBuildProviderHandler, CrystalDecisions.Shared, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304, Custom=null" />
       <section name="crystalReportViewer" type="System.Configuration.NameValueSectionHandler" />
  </sectionGroup>
</sectionGroup>
  </configSections>

<businessObjects>
  <crystalReports>
    <rptBuildProvider>
      <add embedRptInResource="true" />
    </rptBuildProvider>
    <crystalReportViewer>
          <add key="ResourceUri" value="/crystalreportviewers13" />
  </crystalReportViewer>
  </crystalReports>
</businessObjects>
```

Right after **< configuration >** tag in web.config file. for me any other place did not work and generated Error message.

Answer (score 1):

For me, the webpage Developer Tools (F12 then Console tab) showed that the server was looking for root/aspnet_client/system_web/4_6_1069 folder when I had copied the files into the 4_0_30319 folder.  I renamed the folder and BAM!

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to deploy it as .Net 4, not .Net 4.5.

Answer (score 0):

For those of us running migrated projects from .Net 4.0 or lower to 4.5+ I have made an observation. It seems if your page that contains the viewer is in a subdirectory then the image urls are being generated relative to that page and not to the root of the web application. E.g if your page is /gl/accounts.aspx then the image may be /gl/crystalimagehandler.aspx etc A quick way to fix this is to change your handler mapping to a wildcard ending in crystalimagehandler.aspx or put the following code in Global.asax

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var p = Request.Path.ToLower().Trim();
            if (p.EndsWith("/crystalimagehandler.aspx") && p!= "/crystalimagehandler.aspx")
            {
                var fullPath=Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.ToLower();
                var index = fullPath.IndexOf("/crystalimagehandler.aspx");
                Response.Redirect(fullPath.Substring(index));
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a situation where I had some Crystal Reports created using connection "SQL Server Native Client 11.0" and some using connection "Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server". Both worked on our old server running IIS 6. However, when we migrated over to a new server running IIS 8.5, some reports worked as expected, while others displayed an empty Crystal Reports viewer. After 4-5 days of pulling my hair out and trying everything I could think of, I finally compared everything between the reports that worked vs. the reports that did not work. What I discovered was the reports that worked used the "Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server" connection. Once I made this change, the reports served up perfectly.